# Aligning text annotation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a test df:

```
a <- 5:8
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I'd like to create a bar plot and add text above each bar, a certain distance beneath the top, thus I use `y=Inf, vjust=2`, however the letters are now aligned by their tops and not the bottom of the letter (i.e. they don't sit on the same horizontal line). Is there a way to change that (without having to fiddle around with the values to something like `vjust=2.45` or so for the "shorter" ones)?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,9)) +
  annotate('text', x=1, y=Inf, vjust=2, label = "a", parse=TRUE) + 
  annotate('text', x=2, y=Inf, vjust=2, label = "a", parse=TRUE) + 
  annotate('text', x=3, y=Inf, vjust=2, label = "b", parse=TRUE) + 
  annotate('text', x=4, y=Inf, vjust=2, label = "b", parse=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: Use a single "annotate" command instead of multiple ones.
Edit: If the `parse` argument is set to `TRUE` (as in your snippet), this method fails.
:) Good luck.

```
library(ggplot2)

a <- 5:8
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df <- data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(df, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10)) +
# This is the difference to yor code:
annotate("text", x = 1:4, y = Inf,  vjust=2, label = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
```

[image]

This is actually included in the R documentation of `annotate`: (last line of `?annotate`)

```
p + annotate("text", x = 2:3, y = 20:21, label = c("my label", "label 2"))
```

Comment: That's awesome, wasn't aware that this is possible. Thanks!